# -bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, iptables, logging

I am trying to log iptables actions so I can trouble shoot why a FORWARD rule isn't working and I need to run this command:

```
echo ipt_LOG >/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log/2
```

this is after loading the logging module "`sudo modprobe ipt_LOG`" and I keep getting this error even when I have switch to root (`sudo -i`) and am in the location of the said file '2':

```
root@george-jendoc-node:/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log# echo "ipt_LOG" > 2
-bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

I did a `stat 2` and I got:

```
File: 2
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
Device: 4h/4d   Inode: 185636      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-05-12 12:27:05.420721533 +0000
Modify: 2020-05-12 12:33:44.449767903 +0000
Change: 2020-05-12 12:33:44.449767903 +0000
 Birth: -
```

I clearly see the file in question but why am I getting the 'no such file or directory' error and how do I write to that file?

UPDATE:

`cat 2` shows `NONE` and `echo ipt_LOG` shows 'ipt_LOG'.

Comment: What does `cat 2` shows? And also, what does `echo ipt_LOG` shows without redirecting its output to file?

Comment: See my update @gryu

Comment: what happens if you try: echo -e "ipt_LOG\0" > ...

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I think, these numbered files in `nf_log` folder are system protected. In case of trying to access file `2` and saving changes using `vim.tiny` it says: `"2" E667: Fsync failed`. But even in case you could write to that file, your `echo ipt_LOG` does nothing except of printing `ipt_LOG`. If you check your loaded kernel modules, you'll not find `ipt_LOG` module. So it is just a string for `echo`. Use `$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*' | grep ipt_` to see kernel modules.

Comment: I do not understand why you need to write to that location at all. Normally it is managed automatically, based on what you are doing in iptables. I log from iptables all the time, and don't do this.

Comment: Are references to ipt_LOG as a module, and having to force load a module at all, obsolete? I do not have a ipt_LOG module. If I use logging in iptables that field will self populate and the module will autoload as required. Example: Before: `cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log/2` gives `NONE`; after: gives `nf_log_ipv4`. (Can also be done via force loading the module, but not required.)

Comment: @dougsmythies I was following some instruction on how to log iptables activities and a step involved writing to that location.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue when following these guides:
https://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/
https://www.opsist.com/blog/2015/08/11/how-do-i-see-what-iptables-is-doing.html

After some digging around it seems at least in CentOS 7 the correct commands are `modprobe nf_log_ipv4` and `sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4`. Not sure whether the information in those guides is outdated or if it's a Redhat vs Debian sort of thing, but this guide helped in my case:
https://www.opensourcerers.org/2016/05/27/how-to-trace-iptables-in-rhel7-centos7/